# Excel VBA Worksheet_Change

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that checks for text in a range of cells and opens a MsgBox

The code works well until I delete a range of data both from using a macro for `ClearContents` and selecting a range of cells and using the delete button. *No error if I delete cell contents one cell at a time*.

The original code would trigger the `MsgBox` for every change; I just want it to trigger based on the entry of "Not Met" from a pick list.

The error I get is this:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Following is the modified code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("E3:E41")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then


        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.

        If Target.Value = ("Not Met") Then
        MsgBox "Make sure you enter Gaps, Actions and a Priority Rating"

    End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That is because you have more than on cell selected when this runs.  You need to put in a check to only run if only one cell is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real need to have a Range variable to keep the the Range("E3:E41"), you can do it directly with `If Not Intersect(Range("E3:E41"), Target) Is Nothing Then`.

Note: Since `Target` is a Range, there is no need to use it with `Range(Target.Address)` , `Target` alone will do it.

**Code** (short version)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("E3:E41"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been changed
        If Target.Value = ("Not Met") Then MsgBox "Make sure you enter Gaps, Actions and a Priority Rating"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are after:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("E3:E41")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then


        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.

        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value = ("Not Met") Then
                MsgBox "Make sure you enter Gaps, Actions and a Priority Rating"
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```